# Passing Parameter as Integer to Limit

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been using parameters in my PHP application for MySQL Queries.

```
public function getAllPostsForCategoryFrom($CategoryID, $StartPos)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Post WHERE CategoryID = :CategoryID ORDER BY PostID DESC LIMIT :StartPos, 5";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $parameters = array(':CategoryID' => $CategoryID, ':StartPos' => $StartPos);
    $query->execute($parameters);
    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

In the function above, it seems to pass $StartPos as a string which just throws an error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0', 5' at line 1

I have tried to cast the passed value as an integer as well however, it seems MySQL does not like to accept casts/convert in the limit.

```
CAST(:StartPos AS UNSIGNED);
```

I am aware of binding parameters like this:

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM tbl_news ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT :start, :rows";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->bindParam(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$q->bindParam(':rows',$rows, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

However, I'm unsure how to do that with the kind of parameters I have been using. Would appreciate any pointers on how I can get the value passed as an integer and not a string!

**EDIT: ** I should have mentioned this was MySQL compatible Aurora on AWS

Comment: Arithmetic cast/expressions `LIMIT (1*:Param), 5` work for recent versions.

Comment: That's a nice one but its still giving me an error. Ah, is it possible it's not working as this is Aurora on AWS?